# Firefox addon installation through windows registry (windows 10)

Tags: firefox-addon

I would like to install a Firefox addon through the windows regsitry.
I've tried to update different entries in the registry but non of them worked for me.
Is someone managed to do that?

I've tried different entries in the registry including the policies section and the firefox/extenstions section.